# What corresponds to asEagerSingleton in HK2 in Jersey 2?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, guice, hk2

I am developing a REST API using Jersey 2 and I need some of my classes to be instantiated on start up and not just when some resource request triggers it.

So what I am asking is: how do I achieve that an instance of `SomethingImpl` defined below here is created on server start up and not just when someone hits the something resource? In Guice I would use `.asEagerSingleton()`.

Application:

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication() {
        register(new AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(" else").to(String.class);
                bind(SomethingImpl.class).to(Something.class).in(Singleton.class);
            }
        });

        register(SomeResource.class);
    }
}
```

Something:

```
public interface Something {
   String something();
}

public class SomethingImpl implements Something {
    @Inject
    public SomethingImpl(final String something) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println(something() + something);

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(4000);

                    } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    public String something() {
        return "Something";
    }
}
```

Some resource:

```
@Path("/")
public class SomeResource {
    private final Something something;

    @Inject
    public SomeResource(final Something something) {
        this.something = something;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("something")
    public String something() {
        return something.something();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just create and bind an instance of `SomethingImpl` instead of binding the class type?

Comment: In this simplified code, yes. But in my real code the classes I need instantiated have constructors taking several injected objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a later release of hk2 than is integrated with Jersey (but which will be integrated soon) you can have services that are marked @Immediate.  These basically get started as soon as they are added to hk2.  However, in order to make it work you will have to add the Immediate context to the system (e.g. https://hk2.java.net/2.2.0-b27/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/utilities/ServiceLocatorUtilities.html#enableImmediateScope%28org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator%29)

It would be a good idea to lobby with the Jersey team to have this scope/context pair enabled by default (they already enable things like PerThread scope)

I have created this issue: https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2291 to request that Jersey enable @Immediate services by default

Comment: Sounds promising :) But how do I call `ServiceLocatorUtilities.enableImmediateScope` when it is not supported by the HK2 included in Jersey?

Comment: I don't think that you can.  You'll have to wait for a version of Jersey with a high enough version of hk2.  I believe that will happen very soon in the new year, so you may have to wait until then

Comment: Thought so ;) Thanks for sharing your knowledge about `@Immediate`. I will give up for now and just create the objects I need at start up manually.

Answer (score 0):

Write an implementation of a javax.servlet.ServletContextListener and add that listener to your web xml.

http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/what-is-listener-servletcontextlistener-example/

Comment: But in my servlet context listener I cannot have injected objects?

Comment: at my work we use spring with our servlet context listeners, and it definitely injects dependencies into the listener.  I think it works as long as the spring servlet context listener is listed before your listener, but I'm not entirely sure about that.  Of course you will also have to define the listener as a spring bean in your app context.

Comment: I would prefer not to mix several dependency injection frameworks. Maybe I should just give up on HK2 and switch to Guice or Spring instead. It's just a bit annoying at this stage ;)

Comment: sorry I didn't realize what you were using for dependency injection, I never heard of HK2 or Guice.  Spring and EJBs are the only dependency injection frameworks I have seen on job openings.  I heard that EJBs are not popular any more.  Yeah, mixing DI frameworks is definitely a bad idea.  I would not give up yet if I were you, I would try moving some things around, and double checking what is in your app context (if HK2 has that).  For example, I might try putting @Inject on a constructor instead, and naming my listener, but like I said, I'm not familiar with HK2.

Answer (score 0):

Besides what msknapp said, you can also use [@WebListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebListener.html) for the servlet context listener so that you don't have to add the listener to web.xml. Then your listener will look like

```
@WebListener
public class SomethingListener implements ServletContextListener {
    @Inject
    private final Something something;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        //put code about something here
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do that the something does not get injected?

Comment: I use Spring as the dependency injection framework with Jersey. I haven't used HK2 before. I'd suggest to not mess up with other framework if you are already using Spring. An example of Jersey with Spring can be found [here](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/2.4.1/examples/helloworld-spring-webapp).

Comment: I am not using Spring... at least not what I am aware of :D